# How to resize DIV with background image?

Tags: html, background-image

Quite new to CSS3 and I have a issue with the DIV not changing height as the background-image get's larger (height). The DIV should expand as the background image is expanding. After this DIV there will be a footer with fixed height.

The web page:
http://www.cre.fi/kalustekeskus/

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#full-screen-background-image {
    background-image: url(../img/kalustekeskus_bg.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 90%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Kalustekeskus</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="full-screen-background-image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any smart way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: In which browser are you testing. Looks like its working fine in chrome.

Comment: DIV not changing height in Firefox, latest versions both Mac and Windows. The DIV container should change it's height as the background-image change.

Comment: Please post your code here.

Comment: Code posted in my first post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the website you have used min-weight:600px; change this to min-height:90%.

You can specify the min-height in percentage then the div will expand with respect to the actions you do in the image.

Comment: Thanks, although as I resize the browser (wider), the DIV doesn't expand with the background image, the image will get cropped in the DIV.